# Проверка правописания в Intellij Idea для русского текста

Tags: intellij-idea, проверка-орфографии

Как настроить проверку правописания (орфографии) в Intellij Idea для русского текста?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для phpstorm (думаю, что и в других продуктах jetbrains) есть решение проще и правильнее скачивания словаря 2010 года.

**UPD: В версиях, начиная с 2021.2.1 эту настройку переместили в Natural Languages:**

File | Settings | Editor | Natural Languages

[image: в поиске вбиваем 'natural language']

Переходим в меню "File | Settings | Editor | Proofreading", где видим установленный язык 'english (usa)':

[image: открытие настроек]

жмем на плюсик и добавляем русский язык:

[image: добавление русского языка]

и сохраняем.

Comment: К сожалению, в ReSharper нет таких пунктов в настройках, только старый .dic-словарь, но он теперь требует также .aff-файл.

Comment: путь в phpstorm 2023.3.3 изменен: English is enabled by default. To add other languages, open Settings/Preferences | Editor | Natural Languages. Плюс необходимо наличие плагина Grazie lite

Answer (score 9):

Для WebStorm на mac это тоже работает.

1. Скачиваем словарь http://www.winedt.org/dict.html
2. Распаковываем архив. Он представляет собой три словаря.
3. Добавляем словари. WebStorm -> Preferences -> Editor -> Spelling -> Dictionaries -> внизу нажать плюсик "Add custom dictionaries".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Теперь у .dic-файлу нужен также .aff-файл, а где его взять, не ясно.

Answer (score 6):

Для установки доп. словарей нужно:

1. Скачать [словарь](http://www.winedt.org/dict.html).
2. Установить в Intellij Idea: Settings → Editor → Spelling → Custom Dictionaries.

Comment: Спасибо! В идеале ещё словарь бы поновее

Answer (score 4):

Если отсутствует пункт **Natural Languages**

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Natural Languages

Нужно установить плагин **Grazie** и перезапустить IDE (в моем случае RubyMine 2022.1), тогда он появиться и можно добавить русский язык или любой другой.

Comment: Это решает проблему для Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

## На PyCharm версии 2021.3.1

Актуально следующее:

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Natural Languages

[image: Тырк]